# Authentication user to web application from desktop application

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, google-chrome, process.start

I am a novice programmer. I need write desktop application, where user enters the username and password. After clicked on button calls the method Start class Process. Unfortunately, appears in an error message System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception, username or password is incorrect.

My code:

```
//Download data
String user = this.textBoxUser.Text;
String pass = this.textBoxPassword.Text;

//Password
 SecureString secret = SecureStringConverter.ConvertToSecureString(pass);            
//Webbrowser
string file = "chrome.exe";
string domain = @"http://localhost:62074/";
//Process start
Process proc = new Process();

Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey subKey = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey(@"http\shell\open\command");
String DefaultBrowser = subKey.GetValue(null).ToString();

if (DefaultBrowser != null)
{
   int startIndex = DefaultBrowser.IndexOf("\"") + 1;
   int endIndex = DefaultBrowser.IndexOf("\"", startIndex);
   string RegDefaultBrowserPath = DefaultBrowser.Substring(startIndex, endIndex - startIndex);

   proc.StartInfo.FileName = RegDefaultBrowserPath;
   proc.StartInfo.Arguments = domain;
   proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
   proc.StartInfo.LoadUserProfile = false;
   proc.StartInfo.UserName = user;
   proc.StartInfo.Password = secret;
   proc.Start();
}
```

And this method to convert string to SecureString

```
public static class SecureStringConverter
{
   public static SecureString ConvertToSecureString(string password)
   {
      if (password == null)
         throw new ArgumentNullException("password");

      unsafe
      {
         fixed (char* passwordChars = password)
         {
            var securePassword = new SecureString(passwordChars, password.Length);
            securePassword.MakeReadOnly();
            return securePassword;
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your intent. Are you trying to forward user credentials into Chrome browser?

Comment: Yes. I try to forward user credentials into the Chrome browser to authenticate him in web application.

Comment: Why do you need to start Chrome as a different user?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your approach will work. At least not as simple as you might expect it to happen. You may get it working by launching Internet Explorer with explicit credentials to authenticate against applications hosted in IIS, as they may be configured to use domain account for authentication. This scenario essentially is for Intranet web applications. With Crome it is a completely different story.

Merits of your approach are completely not obvious. It is expected that credentials of user logged in to Windows are used for authentication. With your idea, it sounds more like someone else signs in to Windows for me, and I use my own credentials to run web app, but still use remaining windows apps with someone else's credentials.

The following article should give you an idea that it will depend on infrastructure support, and specific sign in process, not just as simple as forwarding explicit credentials to get it working with external web applications who knows nothing about your domain:

https://support.google.com/a/answer/60224?hl=en